# UI focus bug, focus jumps back to last edited textbox after tab

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have an annoying, somewhat odd bug. I have a grid in knockout that has several columns, of which one is editable. This column generates a textbox input for each row.

When the user edits one row and then tabs onto the next one, the focus will jump back to the row that was just edited. This will only happen once, so if you tab again, you can tab on to the next boxes.

If you do not edit a textbox, the jump back behaviour will not occur. I am having a hard time seeing what exactly is causing this behaviour.

Code for the knockout grid in the view:

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-striped center table-hover" style="clear: both; margin-bottom: 10px;" id="resultsTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="col-md-2"><b>Culture</b></th>
                        <th class="col-md-2"><b>Section</b></th>
                        <th class="col-md-2"><b>Name</b></th>
                        <th class="col-md-2"><b>Value</b></th>
                        <th class="col-md-2"><b>LastChangeOn</b></th>
                        <th class="col-md-2"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody data-bind='foreach: Items'>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="col-md-2">
                            <span data-bind="text: Culture"></span>
                        </td>
                        <td class="col-md-2">
                            <span data-bind="text: Section"></span>
                        </td>
                        <td class="col-md-2">
                            <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
                        </td>
                        <td class="col-md-2">
                            <input type="text" data-bind="value: Value" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="col-md-2">
                            <span data-bind="text: LastChangeOn"></span>
                        </td>
                        <td class="col-md-2">
                            <span data-bind="text: Id, visible: false"></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Code for the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _VM;
var initialLoad = true;

$(function () {
    LoadKnockoutContent(true);
});

$("#SearchButton").on("click", function (e) {
    _VM.moveToFirstPage();
});

IndexModel = function (initialData) {
    var _self = this;

    PagedViewModel.call(_self);

    _self.Items = ko.observableArray();

    _self.CurrentPage.subscribe(function (value) {
        $("#SearchCriteria_HiddenPage").val(value);

        LoadKnockoutContent(false, _self.Release);
    });

    _self.loadModelData = function (data) {
        _self.CurrentPage(data.CurrentPage);
        _self.PageSize = data.PageSize;
        _self.MaxPageIndex(data.PageCount);
        _self.Items(ToResourcesArray(data.Resources, _self));
    }

    _self.loadModelData(initialData);
};

ResourceModel = function (item, parent) {
    var _self = this;

    _self.Parent = parent;
    _self.Id = item.Id;
    _self.Culture = ko.observable(item.Culture);
    _self.Section = ko.observable(item.Section);
    _self.Name = ko.observable(item.Name);
    _self.Value = ko.observable(item.Value);

    _self.Value.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        // Send the new value to the backend
        SaveResource(newValue, item.Id);
    });

    if (!item.LastChangeOn == "") {
        _self.LastChangeOn = ko.observable(parseJsonDate(item.LastChangeOn).toPaddedDateTimeString());
    }
    else {
        _self.LastChangeOn = ko.observable(item.LastChangeOn);
    }
}

function ToResourcesArray(data, parent) {
    var items = ko.utils.arrayMap(data, function (item) {
        return new ResourceModel(item, parent);
    });

    return items;
}

    function LoadKnockoutContent(initialLoad, callback, callback2) {
    // Call to the back end, passing along the search criteria
    }

    function SaveResource(newValue, Id) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("UpdateResource", "Resource")',
            data: JSON.stringify({ id: Id, newValue: newValue }),
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            contentType: 'application/json;',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.isSuccess) {
                    // Success, we need to reload here as well else the last changed on field is not updated in the grid overview
                    LoadKnockoutContent(false);
                } else {
                    alertify.error(data.message);
                    // Refresh the view else the value field will stay empty while it is not saved.
                    // A reload will show the grid again with the previous value.
                    LoadKnockoutContent(false);
                }
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                alert(request.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

dd

Comment: Would you mind trying to reduce the size of your code to a minimal version which would be easier for people to answer and be useful for others in the future?

Comment: Yes ofcourse, I will try to minimize it as much as possible

Comment: @WalterMacambira I reduced the view code, but I am not sure if I can reduce the JS code further, as I have no idea in which part the issue may lay. The JS code I posted is all used for the Knockout Grid.

Comment: In these cases, as @WalterMacambira wrote, we should try to disable all the code that is not essential for loading the grid. Sometimes I prefer to use a small empty project (jsFiddle, CodePen, etc.) and gradually add the code until I reply the error. So, in your case, you could try for example to comment the SaveResource line (newValue, item.Id) in the _self.Value.subscribe, but it is only a hypothesis.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to find what caused the bug. The grid was reloaded after every call to the save method, while it only should occur on a fail to save.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue.

The issue was that the Grid was reloaded after ever call to the save function. This should only occur when the save failed. If the grid is reloaded after every save, then when you tab, you will start at the first row of the Grid again.